# Problem in Equating Coefficient of Elliptic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let,  $E:=y^2=x^3 + Ax + B$ an elliptic curve, 2 points  $P, -Q, Q$ on $E$ such that $2P=Q$, we can write

$$y^2-(x^3 + Ax + B) = (x - e_1)(x - e_2)^2=0$$
Where, $e_1=x(Q), e_2=x(P)$ a double root. So, 
$y=m(x-x(Q))+y(Q)$, here $y$ is the  line that goes thorough $P, Q$, and $m$ is the slope.

$$ (x - e_1)(x^2 - 2xe_2+e_2^2)$$
$$=(x^3 - 2x^2e_2+xe_2^2)-(x^2e_1 - 2xe_1e_2+e_1e_2^2)$$
$$=x^3 - 2x^2e_2+xe_2^2-x^2e_1 + 2xe_1e_2-e_1e_2^2$$
$$=x^3 + x^2(-1)(2e_2+e_1) +x(e_2^2+ 2e_1e_2)+(-1)e_1e_2^2$$

From $y^2-x^3 + Ax + B =0$ we get coefficient of $x^2$ is $(-1)m^2$, equating coefficient we find,  $m^2=(2e_2+e_1)$.

Problem is , if I simplify both side and then equate the coefficient, then, I get correct coefficient of $x^2$ but not for $x$ (if we plug in value of $x, y$ coordinate of points $P, Q$, the coefficients of $x^2$ satisfies only, not $x$).

What is the problem?

**Edit:**

$x(P), y(P)$ are the co-ordinate with respect to $x$ and $y$ axis respectively, for point $P$.

$A, B$ are integer and  $(x,y)$ is point on $E.$

I have the below identities:

$$2e_2+e_1=m^2,$$

$$ e_2(e_2+2e_1)=A+2m(mx(Q)-y(Q)),$$

$$e_1e_2^2=B-(y(Q)-mx(Q))^2$$.

but it does not work for last 2, try this : Let $E$ be the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 − 25x$, $P = (−4,6), 2P = (\frac{1681}{ 144} ,\frac{ −62279}{ 1728 }), m = \frac{23} {12}.$

Comment: Are you aware that your parentheses and overall notations aren't exactly clear?

Comment: @Mindlack No, I tried to follow silverman's book, do you mean $x(P), y(P)$? Could u point out plz?

Comment: How about the infamous $y^2-x^3+Ax+B$? What are precisely $x,y$ here? And shouldn't it be $y^2-(x^3+Ax+B)$?

Comment: @Mindlack edited (see the last paragraph under *edit*) and corrected. let me know any other confusing terms.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m'$ be the slope of the line going through $P$ and $-Q$, ie the tangent to the elliptic curve at $P$.

What we *know* is that the factorization $x^3+Ax+B-(m'(x-x(-Q))+y(-Q))^2=(x-x(-Q))(x-x(P))^2=(x-e_1)(x^2-2e_2x+e_2^2)$ holds (as $P$,$P$,$-Q$ are collinear).

So, $x^3-m'^2x^2+x(A+2m'^2x(Q)+2m'y(Q))+B-(y(Q)+m'x(Q))^2=x^3-(2e_2+e_1)x^2+e_2(e_2+2e_1)x-e_1e_2^2$.

Therefore $2e_2+e_1=m'^2$, $e_2(e_2+2e_1)=A+2m'(m'x(Q)+y(Q))$, $e_1e_2^2=B-(y(Q)+m'x(Q))^2$. Do these identities work?

Comment: but it does not work for last 2, try this : Let $E$ be the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 − 25x$, $P = (−4,6), 2P = (\frac{1681}{ 144} ,\frac{ −62279}{ 1728 }), m = \frac{23} {12}.$

Comment: Would u plz check your post, probably there are some error in first equation.

Comment: I edited. Does it work now?

Comment: No, your  result 3 identities are same, you can check  yourself, btw, probably I misunderstood  your first equation, it was okay.

Comment: I edited again a couple of signs. But I'm not using $m$. Remember that the points that are collinear are $P$ and $-Q$.